# How do I compile mercurial 1.5.2 on debian?

Tags: debian, packages, build, dpkg

I downloaded the files for Mercurial 1.5.2 from http://packages.debian.org/sid/mercurial (mercurial_1.5.2-1.debian.tar.gz,  mercurial_1.5.2-1.dsc and mercurial_1.5.2.orig.tar.gz). How do I get a .deb package out of these? I tried to follow the instructions at http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-build.en.html but they don't work.

I tried to unpack the two archives and run `dpkg-buildpackage` or `debian/rules build` but that fails with:

```
dh --with quilt clean
   dh_testdir
   debian/rules override_dh_auto_clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/packages/mercurial-deb'
cp -a mercurial/__version__.py mercurial/__version__.py.save
cp: cannot stat `mercurial/__version__.py': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_clean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/packages/mercurial-deb'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

That's because the directory `mercurial` is inside `mercurial_1.5.2/`. Why doesn't the build script `cd` into the right place? If I try `../debian/rules build`, I get

```
dh --with quilt build
dh: cannot read debian/control: No such file or directory
```

*sigh*

How do I compile a package for debian???

Comment: Should be on SO?

Comment: This isn't about programming but "how do I use software". But it's a grey area, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to recompile it? Well whatever.
First, grab them with: `dget -u --insecure http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mercurial/mercurial_1.5.2-1.dsc`

Then run those commands. This will pack them into a deb like in the archive.

(I would just add a sid.list into my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and use apt-pinning since it grabs every needed dependencies, etc etc. You should check `apt-pinning` out if you just want a newer version.)

Comment: Thanks, that works. My reason is that I have a patch which I need and I really don't want to pollute my system with unknown packages at this time, so no "sid" for me (whatever that might be - it's my first contact with debian).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the [mercurial_1.5.2-1.debian.tar.gz](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mercurial/mercurial_1.5.2-1.debian.tar.gz) file as well. Extract this into the right place and you should be good to go.

The `orig` file is the source code that the Debian people have got hold of. The `debian` file contains the changes they have made to the package, including all the information on how the `.deb` file needs to be built.

Comment: The "right place" was what I was missing. I unpacked the `debian` directory along with the orig sources instead of inside of it.